# Como Subir y leer PDF en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Logro guardar el PDF, pero al leerlo con este metodo me lanza el error de la imagen anterior

```
public function getImage($filename){
        $file = Storage::disk('users')->get($filename);
        return new Response($file, 200);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para trabajar con PDF en laravel te recomiendo trabajar con un filesystem, guardas la ruta en la BD

```
//Aqui manejas el request
  public function crearVersionDocumento($request, $documento){

     $version = VersionDocumento::create([
   //Ojo aqui es en donde asignas la ruta del file a donde ira el documento en este caso es en la carpeta public/ pero puedes definir la carpeta que quieras
    'ruta_documento' => $request -> file('documento') -> store('public/')
  ]);
  //Subimos el documento despues de la creacion del registro en la base de datos

}
```

Y ya con la ruta en la bd y el documento en el file puedes hacer una consulta:

```
public function getDocumento($id_ruta_documento){
return $documento = Documento::findOrFail($id_ruta_documento);
```

}

Ahora que tienes esto lo tienes acceso al documento en PDF, y ya solo lo muestras en el navegador:

```
          <a href="{{ Storage::url($documento -> ruta_documento) }}" class="btn-descargar" target="_blank">
            <i class="fas fa-download"></i>
          </a>
```

Y de esa forma podrás manipular PDF por medio de un filesystem

Answer (score 1):

Prueba poniendo el mime type en el encabezado 'Content-Type':

```
return response( Storage::disk('users')->get($filename), 200)
    ->header('Content-Type', Storage::disk('users')
        ->mimeType($filename)
    );
```